# Is there a way to set a test variable in Java using Robot Framework?

Tags: java, automation, robotframework

I am trying to call the BuiltIN keyword 'Set Test Variable' in java. The reason being is that I want to declare some variables that are read in from the test data.

I have searched and tried many times without success. I have something like:

```
Selenium2Library selenium2Library = Selenium2Library.getLibraryInstances();
String[] test = new String[1];
test[0] = "hello";
selenium2Library.runKeyword("Log", test);
```

This gives a null pointer exception error. I get the same error when instead of Log I use Set Test Variable, which is what I want. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "read in from the test variables?" Where is this Java code executing in relation to your Robot Framework tests? Is this a part of a   Library file, or external from your tests completely?

Comment: read in from the test data is a Java keyword that robot can call.